# How do I get the sum x^n/n! in prolog?

Tags: prolog, sum, factorial

I don't understand much about Prolog. I need to count a sum **x^n/n!** in Prolog, **n=1..k, k and x integer numbers**
Someone, please explain me how to do this using Prolog. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

By implementing the loop with a tail-recursive auxiliary predicate with accumulator parameters:

```
xsum(K,X,S):- K>=1, zsum(X,1,K,1,0,S).

zsum(X,I,K,PrevTerm,PrevSum,S):-
  I=:=K, Term is ________ * X / I, S is _____ + _____.

zsum(X,I,K,PrevTerm,PrevSum,S):-
  I < K, Term is ________ * X / I, Sum is _____ + _____, I1 is I+1,
  zsum(X,I1,K,Term,Sum,S).
```

Fill in the blanks. :)

The clauses are mutually exclusive so the predicate is deterministic.